# Oracle SQL Multiple count if in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm trying to do some reporting with SQL, but i'm having problems to count in one row multiple the different states by proffesional.

Here is the data sample:

| appointment_key | proffessional | state_type | date_init | date_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | scheduled | 11/10/2020 | 12/10/2020 |
| 1 | John Doe | attended | 12/10/2020 | NULL |
| 2 | John Doe | scheduled | 12/10/2020 | 12/10/2020 |
| 2 | John Doe | attended | 12/10/2020 | NULL |
| 3 | Jane Doe | scheduled | 11/10/2020 | 12/10/2020 |
| 3 | Jane Doe | attended | 12/10/2020 | NULL |
| 4 | Jane Doe | scheduled | 11/10/2020 | 12/10/2020 |
| 4 | Jane Doe | waiting | 12/10/2020 | NULL |
| 5 | John Doe | scheduled | 12/10/2020 | 14/10/2020 |
| 5 | John Doe | canceled | 14/10/2020 | NULL |

I'm trying to showsomething like this, but ONLY the last state of the appointment:

| Proffesional | total_scheduled | total_attended | total_waiting | total_canceled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Jane Doe | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I tried to make a query that counts only the appointments that have NULL date_end (found it on this site), like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT prof.surname, 
SUM(CASE WHEN state_type.name = 'scheduled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_scheduled, 
SUM(CASE WHEN state_type.name = 'attended' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_attended, 
SUM(CASE WHEN state_type.name = 'waiting' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_waiting, 
SUM(CASE WHEN state_type.name = 'canceled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_canceled 
FROM (appointment, appointment_state, prof, state_type, etc.)
WHERE appointment_state.final_date IS NULL
```

(i know i don't need to include the state_type table, but it's for showing the example)

The problem is that this query still counts all states from appointment x, no matter the WHERE statement:

| Proffesional | total_scheduled | total_attended | total_waiting | total_canceled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 6 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Jane Doe | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Do you have any ideas or how should I structure the query?

Sorry if i got something wrong, it's my first time posting here :)

Comment: Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the nice JOINS in the FROM part, the code above is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by saying that you have data.  Well, that is the data that should be aggregated.  If this is a query, you can use a CTE:

```
with data as (
      <your query here>
     )
SELECT prof.surname, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'scheduled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_scheduled, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'attended' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_attended, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'waiting' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_waiting, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'canceled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_canceled 
FROM data
WHERE final_date IS NULL
GROUP BY surname
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you! I obtained the totals easily with this.